# Having trouble changing longitude and latitude in app Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, geolocation

I'm creating a weather app using vanilla javascript and one feature of the app is to click a button and let it randomize a new longitude and latitude so that it can change the location and hence the temperature. I've gotten into a bit of a bind wherein whenever I click on the button nothing happens but whenever I `console.log` it, it appears in the console:

```
changeLocationBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
                longitude = (Math.random() * (80 + 180) + -180).toFixed(3);
                latitude = (Math.random() * (90 + 90) + -90).toFixed(3);
                console.log(latitude, longitude);
            });
```

I dont really know whats going on.

```js
// Selectors
const degreeCelcius = document.querySelector(".celcius");
const weatherDescription = document.querySelector(".description");
const changeLocationBtn = document.querySelector(".change-location-btn");
const weatherLocation = document.querySelector(".location");

// Event Listeners
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let longitude;
  let latitude;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;

      // Here lies the problem
      changeLocationBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        longitude = (Math.random() * (80 + 180) + -180).toFixed(3);
        latitude = (Math.random() * (90 + 90) + -90).toFixed(3);
        console.log(latitude, longitude);
      });

      const corsProxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
      const api = `${corsProxy}http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=7391e8544809410cbf0120949201511&q=${latitude}, ${longitude}`;

      // Fetch data from the API
      fetch(api)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          const {
            temp_c,
            condition
          } = data.current;

          degreeCelcius.textContent = temp_c + '°C';
          weatherDescription.textContent = condition.text;
          weatherLocation.textContent = data.location.name + ", " + data.location.country;
        });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.btn-div {
  height: 250px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.btn-div .change-location-btn {
  background-color: #f82626;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn-div .change-location-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f56969;
  cursor: pointer;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(190deg, #77dfbc, #8b54e6);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.weather-container {
  background-color: #f5e3e3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #131212b2;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #131212b2;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.weather-container h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.weather-container h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="weather-container">
    <h1 class="celcius">Celcius</h1>
    <h4 class="description">Sunny Day</h4>
    <h4 class="location">Planet Vegeta</h4>

    <div class="btn-div">
      <button class="change-location-btn">Change Location</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `getCurrentPosition` is executed properly and returns no error? Because you are not handling its potential errors. Add a second callback function, logging potential errors (CORS issues, etc). Because you attach the click event only in the case when `getCurrentPosition` went well.

Comment: In snippets here: `Geolocation has been disabled in this document by Feature Policy.`

Comment: Set `<button class="change-location-btn">Change Location</button>` button type to button `type="button"` because the default type is 'submit' which is send form and refresh the page

Comment: Ok, just changed, the coordinates still aren't changing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code send data only one, when the page loaded. I modified the JS code to working with both mode onLoad and click events. But the changing the displayed data is very slowly.
An I experienced the weather API only work with ground coordinates, not working in the seas and oceans.

```
const degreeCelcius = document.querySelector(".celcius");
const weatherDescription = document.querySelector(".description");
const changeLocationBtn = document.querySelector(".change-location-btn");
    
const weatherLocation = document.querySelector(".location");

const corsProxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

function change_location(longitude,latitude){
                
    const api = ${corsProxy}http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=7391e8544809410cbf0120949201511&q=${latitude}, ${longitude}`;

    // Fetch data from the API
    fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
        //console.log(response);
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const {
           temp_c,
           condition
        } = data.current;

        degreeCelcius.textContent = temp_c + '°C';
        weatherDescription.textContent = condition.text;
        weatherLocation.textContent = data.location.name + ", " + data.location.country;
    });
}

// Event Listeners
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let longitude;
    let latitude;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            console.log("Current location: " + latitude, longitude);

            change_location(longitude,latitude);
        });
    }
});

changeLocationBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    longitude = (Math.random() * (80 + 180) + -180).toFixed(3);
    latitude = (Math.random() * (90 + 90) + -90).toFixed(3);
    console.log(latitude, longitude);

    change_location(longitude,latitude);
});`
```

Comment: Yes this worked thank you. What do you think might be the reason as to why the data is loading so slowly?

Comment: I think the process the data of geolocation in server-side is slow, the problem not in your site. Now I readed other similar portals other users also experienced slow response from API (and other weather APIs)

Answer (score 0):

You can check that changeLocationBtn really exists and is found when listener is bind also it's better to add changeLocationBtn selector near changeLocationBtn.addEventListener to check if its still in context.

```
 const changeLocationBtn = document.querySelector(".change-location-btn");
 console.log('btn', changeLocationBtn )
 changeLocationBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        longitude = (Math.random() * (80 + 180) + -180).toFixed(3);
        latitude = (Math.random() * (90 + 90) + -90).toFixed(3);
        console.log(latitude, longitude);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I've just checked and it seems like everything is binded properly but still cant get the coordinates to change.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

```
 // Event Listeners
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let longitude;
  let latitude;

  const degreeCelcius = document.querySelector(".celcius");
  const weatherDescription = document.querySelector(".description");
  const changeLocationBtn = document.querySelector(".change-location-btn");
  const weatherLocation = document.querySelector(".location");

  // Here lies the problem
  changeLocationBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    longitude = (Math.random() * (80 + 180) + -180).toFixed(3);
    latitude = (Math.random() * (90 + 90) + -90).toFixed(3);
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
  });
```